# Find string in wildcard file and if string is not found put filename on text file CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

Hi how can I translate this to a batch file code

If string in *.txt is not found, store filename to filesthathasnostring.txt

basically i want to create a list of all the filenames that does not contain a specific string
My attempt fails

```
find "STRING" *.txt || >>fail.txt
```

Comment: `findstr /?`. Take a look at the `/m` switch.

Comment: sorry, `/m` and `/v` don't work well together... See my answer for another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(for %%a in (*.txt) do findstr "STRING" %%a >nul|| echo %%a)>filesthathasnostring.dat
```

the `for` loop allows you to process each file on it's own. Search your string, redirect the output to NUL and if not found, print the filename. Put parantheses around the whole loop to be able to redirect it to a file alltogether.

(if you want to use directly on the command line, replace every `%%a` with `%a`)

Comment: Hi @stephan many thanks this is what i was looking for, i just removed the ) after %%a ... many thanks!

Comment: You need that `)` or it will only write the last filename. `(for %a in (*.bat) do findstr /I "asdf" "%~a" 1>nul || echo "%~a") >filesthathasnostring.dat`